# Is there any C SQLite API for quoting/escaping the name of a table?

Tags: c, sqlite, escaping, quotes

It's impossible to `sqlite3_bind_text` a table name because `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails to prepare a statement such as:

```
SELECT * FROM ? ;
```

I presume the table name is needed to parse the statement, so the quoting needs to have happened before `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.

Is there something like a `sqlite3_quote_tablename`? Maybe it already exists under a name I can't recognize, but I can't find anything in the functions list.

Comment: your proposed sqlite3_quote_tablename function could sanitize the input to prevent sql injection attacks.  To do this it could parse the input to make sure it is a string literal. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue

Comment: A very late response: Thanks, that was the route I took. My former employer owns that code now, though. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your proposed sqlite3_quote_tablename function could sanitize the input to prevent sql injection attacks. To do this it could parse the input to make sure it is a string literal. http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue

Comment: The answer is that my proposed function does not exist, and the link is a useful guide to implement it ;)

Answer (score 2):

SQLite will escape identifiers for you with the `%w` format in the https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html family of functions.

Comment: And with [sqlite3_mprintf](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html) you can call it from C. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If a table name has invalid characters in it you can enclose the table name in double quotes, like this.

```
sqlite> create table "test table" (id);
sqlite> insert into "test table" values (1);
sqlite> select * from "test table";
id
----------
1
```

Of course you should avoid using invalid characters whenever possible.  It complicates development and is almost always unnecessary (IMO the only time it is necessary is when you inherit a project that is already done this way and it's too big to change).

Comment: The problem is to do this programmatically. Is there an official method?

Comment: +1 for being the first source I could find that told me the escape character for tables and columns. Apparently my google-fu is weak today...

Comment: @Charlie Kilian, thanks, sql is pretty consistent from one database to another, the hard part is finding all the little inconsistencies.  Some other databases, like sql server and access, use `[` and `]` for escaping invalid object names.  sqlite ustes `"`, which interestingly can also be used for strings, although `'` is more standard and supported in sqlite and most databases.

Answer (score 1):

When using SQLite prepared statements with parameters the parameter: *"specifies a placeholder in the expression for a literal value that is filled in at **runtime**"*

Before executing any SQL statement, SQLite "compiles" the SQL string into a series of [opcodes](http://www.sqlite.org/opcode.html) that are executed by an internal Virtual Machine.  The table names and column names upon which the SQL statement operates are a *necessary* part of the compilation process.

You *can* use parameters to bind "values" to prepared statements like this:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE name=?;
```

And then call `sqlite3_bind_text()` to bind the string `gavinbeatty` to the already compiled statement.  However, this architecture means that you *cannot* use parameters like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ? WHERE name=?;    // Can't bind table name as a parameter
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE ?=10;    // Can't bind column name as a parameter
```

Comment: I know that the table name cannot be bound because the parse/compile stage requires the table name.

I am looking for an established way to either test that a table name is valid or to canonicalize a table name.

Answer (score 0):

If SQLite doesn't accept table names as parameters, I don't think there is a solution for your problem...

Take into account that:

> Parameters that are not assigned values using sqlite3_bind() are treated as NULL.

so in the case of your query, the table name would be NULL which of course is invalid.

Comment: There is no statement to `sqlite3_step` when `sqlite3_prepare_v2` stage fails.

I'm asking if there is another API available to do something like bind a table name. Something like `printf "%q"` in bash.

edit: formatting

Comment: What I mean is that you can't prepare a statement that could lead to an incorrect binding of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this too and couldn't find it either. In my case, the expected table names were always among a fixed set of tables (so those were easy to validate). The field names on the other hand weren't so I ended up filtering the string, pretty much removing everything that was not a letter, number, or underscore (I knew my fields would fit this parameters). That did the trick.